# How to use this gamma function in this statistics problem?

Tags: integration, statistics, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Can someone explain to me how the steps to get from the top to the bottom (the gamma function)? I do not understand the steps taken in between. I see that the denominator of the fraction gets put in front of the fraction, but I don't understand the rule that allows that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ follows [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)  with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\theta$, then

$$f_X(x; k, \theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} \, dx &=\Gamma(2)\theta^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(2)\theta^2} x^{2-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} \, dx \\
&= \Gamma(2)\theta^2
\end{align}

since 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(2)\theta^2} x^{2-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} \, dx=1$ as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)\theta^2} x^{2-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ is a pdf.

Comment: Thanks, I almost get it-so you are basically using the gamma distribution and letting the frequency parameter be 1/θ, correct?  Thats why the theta is on the bottom in the first line (instead of the top).  Also, on the second line, to the right of the equals sign, you are basically saying the final answer (which is Gamma(2)theta^2) is the result of what we multiply by the integral and what is to the right of it?  Correct?

Comment: Yup, I think your frequency parameter is the rate parameter according to the wikipedia page. $\theta$ is also known as the scale parameter and they are related via $\theta = \frac1{\beta}$. I am using the property that the expression inside the integral is a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $x=t \theta $, the limits will not change $dx  =   \theta dt$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} dx  = \int_{0}^{\infty} t \theta e^{-t}  \theta dt =\theta^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} t  e^{-t}   dt .
\end{eqnarray*}